# Elasticsearch - sub aggregation with a large amount of buckets

Tags: database, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

We have an index with a large amount of user reports (millions / 10s of millions).
Assuming most users have reports, we need to calculate some statistics per-user.
For example, how many users have an average of between 10-15, 15-20, 20-30 reports per week in a specific time interval.
Please note that we don't need to return the buckets themselves in the response, but they need to be evaluated by the sub aggregations that calculate the average & ranges. To my understanding, elasticsearch has a limit to the number of buckets, and it's not recommended to increase it to millions.
I've read about the composite aggregation for pagination, but I don't think this is suitable for this scenario, since we need to calculate aggregate numbers and not return the buckets.

Below is a simplified version of our current query.
We want to calculate the number of uses that have between X1-X2 monthly reports between 2 dates.

1. bucket the reports by user id.
2. use bucket selector to select only the users which have between Y-Z reports (Y1 & Y2 are pre-calculated by the client - these are the numbers which will resolve to an average of between X1-X2 monthly reports).
3. count the number of buckets left

The problem is that the original bucketing (terms aggregation) will only return a relatively small amount of buckets (not millions), so only a small amount of users will be evaluated at all.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

```
POST /reports/_search
{
     "size": 0,
     "query": {
         "range": {
             "timestamp": {
                 "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "lte": "2020-12-24T23:59:59.999Z",
                 "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
             }
         }
     },
     "aggs": {
         "distinctIds_less_than_monthly": {
             "terms": {
                 "field": "userId" // this will only return a small amount of buckets
             },
             "aggs": {
                 "less_than_monthly": {
                     "bucket_selector": {
                         "buckets_path": {
                             "distinctUsers": "distinctUsers_less_than_monthly.value"
                         },
                         "script": "params.distinctUsers > 1000 && params.distinctUsers < 1500"
                     }
                 },
                 "distinctUsers_less_than_monthly": {
                     "value_count": {
                         "field": "userId"
                     }
                 }                 
             }
         },
         "userCount_less_than_monthly": {
             "stats_bucket": {
                 "buckets_path": "distinctIds_less_than_monthly._count"
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see essentially 3 optimizations, all of which share a map → combine approach:

1. Write a script in the language of your choice to **split the 1Y range** into months/weeks, run the queries, and combine the results.
2. Apply some sort of a filter **before** you run the terms aggregations -- calculate the user stats for your most valuable users first (pick them by revenue, their daily active usage etc.), and then for the rest. Then combine.
3. [**Pre-group**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html) the users by, say, the forename initials, and run the `terms` aggs within those groups. Then combine.

Comment: so basically the first 2 options suggest splitting the range/users into groups. The problem is that either I'm going to have lots of groups (e.g. thousands) in which case it would require thousands (if not more) of round-trips from the client to elasticsearch to calculate each group which could take hours, or a small number of groups but each group will still have way more than 10000 users per-group which would still yield the "too many buckets" error. The 3rd option seems to just add an intermediate division, which I'm not sure how it would help.

Comment: Whats the use case of having to retrieve so many buckets at once in the first place? Is it some sort of a yearly report? Do you really need that many?

Comment: yes, it's a periodic report, where the period is defined by the end user.  We don't need each bucket on its own, but we need to count the buckets (as mentioned in the original post), so all the buckets are aggregated into a number.

Comment: I see but wouldn't one single end user limit the whole thing to a single `userId`? Besides, I'd really go w/ the weekly buckets -- you've got 52 requests that certainly won't take days. Plus increasing the max buckets to, say, 50K, should not bring your cluster down. I occasionally do the same thing.

Comment: The end user is an administrator user that needs to get an overview of all users in a specific time period. The system is being used daily by millions or 10s of millions of users, so even after breaking it down to weeks (or even days) will still have millions of users per request (too many buckets)